# How to access buckets with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

Here are my permissions: [image]

Additionally, I have this as a bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::manga-learn-data",
                "arn:aws:s3:::manga-learn-data/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this in my ~/.aws/config file:

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
```

And this in my ~/.aws/credentials file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <access-key>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret-key>
```

Now I do:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
>>> s3.buckets.all()
s3.bucketsCollection(s3.ServiceResource(), s3.Bucket)
>>> for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
...         print(bucket.name)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 83, in __iter__
    for page in self.pages():
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 161, in pages
    pages = [getattr(client, self._py_operation_name)(**params)]
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 262, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 552, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

And you see the traceback there. I am following the steps here: https://github.com/boto/boto3

Any suggestions?

Comment: it only allows the permission for bucket `manga-learn-data`, but your python codes try to go through all buckets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code currently tries to list all buckets but the IAM user does not have permission to do that.

You either have to grant the `ListAllMyBuckets` access to your IAM user, e.g.:

```
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
```

Or you need to change your code to only access the bucket you are interested in:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('manga-learn-data')
for object in bucket:
    # do whatever you need to do here
```